# Running Macros outside Excel to minimize the memory usage of Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code in 6 modules in an Excel workbook. The code in each module is interlinked. I must also mention that I am using the selenium webdriver along with VBA to automate my work. When the macro is run, the code works perfectly functionality wise, but I can't use Excel for anything else at all during this time. The entire program run time is 30 minutes.

I want to be able to use Excel for other operations and not let the macro affect my system performance. Is there a solution to this?

I read somewhere that creating an Excel ribbon through VSTO to run the macro will help reduce the memory impact on Excel. Not too sure about it though.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: This feels quite broad. If it runs correctly and you want to optimize the code then Code Review might be the place. If this is a more general question about the best way to execute your task then maybe superuser? For here, a [mcve] will attract attention .

Comment: But it affects my usage of excel and also makes my system slow and inefficient. I can't perform any other functions in other excel workbooks for the entire run-time of this code. That is effectively, me not being able to work for 45 minutes.

Comment: Use Access for the code, so Excel is usable. Show code! Ever used Winnhttp or ServerXMLHTTP for web automation?

Comment: [A new approach to multithreading in Excel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185212/a-new-approach-to-multithreading-in-excel)

Comment: VSTO won't help, unless there's processing going on that's 100% not reliant on Excel. But why not simply open a separate *instance* of Excel, either using some other Office application, or a desktop shortcut with the appropriate command-line switch? That shouldn't be affected at all by code running in an independent instance.